# How to decouple JSlider action and appearance

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Enabling/disabling JSlider controls both its appearance (enabled/disabled look) and action (whether or not the user can drag the slider thumb). I would like to decouple the two, so that I can explicitly control its appearance (enabled/disabled appearance) independent from its action (draggable/non-draggable thumb).

I tried adding a state change listener to restore the previous slider value if the action is supposed to be "disabled", but this does not preclude other change listeners from using the new value before the old one can be restored.

============================

To avoid questions about UI practices, I will restate the question strictly in terms of appearance, which I now see is the crux of my problem:

How can I change the appearance of a JSlider in a given enable state, such as changing the various colors used to paint it when it is enabled? And other colors when it is disabled?

Comment: Sorry, but once you disable a `JSlider`, its thumb is no longer controllable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? When you disable a component, it can't receive input. An enabled component can receive keyboard and mouse input. It's how it's supposed to be. A component that looks as disabled but still can be interacted with is confusing.

Comment: Correct, so that is not a suitable solution. It seems a solution would likely involve using setEnable() to control behavior, and some kind of manhandling of the component painting to control its appearance, regardless of setEnable() state.

Comment: I want to control behavior (allow/disallow drag to change input) and appearance (normal or grayed out) independently. For example, I want to be able to disable dragging but not have the slider appear grayed out.

Comment: Why do you need it? It's a bad user experience: an active control can be dragged; a disabled control can't be interacted with. Messing with the states is confusing to users of your app.

Comment: Assume this is a thought experiment about how to implement generalized independent control over component behavior and appearance. As to how I want it to appear, whether the control is draggable or not, is specific to my application.

Comment: *How can I change the appearance of a JSlider in a given enable state,*  - Swing components have a `getUI()` and `setUI()` methods. The UI controls how the component is painted. Each Look and Feel will have its own UI code. Sometimes you can control the colors using the UIManager. See: [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).  However, in most cases you will need to override the UI and implement your own custom painting which is not always an easy task.

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/javax/swing for the existing source code. The basic slider UI code is 2,500 lines.